# Pandas read_csv can't find file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I tried to read a csv into a dataframe in Pandas 
it can't find my file what are some possible solutions?

Here is the error:

```
*FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0c537d0c5b39> in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('1.01. Simple linear regression.csv')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
```

Comment: Please  post your code, and use the formatting tools so we can see what is going on.  Also, it is unclear; you mention calling Excel, but you have python tags.  Are you trying to read a CSV file, or call Excel from Python?

Comment: The line of code you posted above assumes your csv file is stored in python working directory. Is it the case? You can run import os; os.getcwd() to determine Python current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you are in the correct directory**

Pandas.read_csv, Python will always look in your “current working directory“

```
data = pd.read_csv('1.01. Simple linear regression.csv')
data.head()
```

**You can always a give a full path**

Pandas.read_csv, Python can also look in a specified folder “current working directory“

I have to do by directory path most of the time myself and set my encoding and add a r before also.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\path\to\your\file\mess.csv', encoding='utf8')
data.head()
```

**you can also rename the file name to keep it simple**

```
1.01. Simple linear regression.csv
```

**into**

```
1_01_Simple_linear_regression.csv


 data = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\path\to\your\file\1_01_Simple_linear_regression.csv')
 data.head()
```

**Sometimes you also need to double \ in the path**

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\path\\1_01_Simple_linear_regression.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the mistake was that i saved the .csv file on another folder, couple with the fact that the path wasn't well defined.

Comment: Cool, I am glad it helped. I did the same a bunch of times when I started too.